# Как нажать Escape, если она отсутствует на клавиатуре при загрузке системы?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hotkeys

При ремонте ноутбука отказала клавиатура и я не могу настроить BIOS, потому что не работает клавиша Escape. К сожалению клавиатуру поставят лишь через месяц и я не могу пользоваться машиной.
Пожалуйста подскажите альтернативные комбинации.

Comment: А как насчёт подсоединить по USB целую клавиатуру?

Comment: USB на материнской убит, нет возможности.

Comment: Для Enter находил в свое время. Вроде бы Cntrl + M

Comment: Остальные клавиши работают.

Comment: Окей, а PS/2 есть?

Comment: Esc = Alt + 27, кажется. Но не уверен, что BIOS такое распознаёт.

Comment: Откуда, типичная современная материна нетбука с отладочным USB. Он то как раз и накрылся =(

Comment: А Ctrl + A не катит в качестве Esc?

Comment: А что мешает выкрутить винт, цепануть его на другой комп и залить ось? Ну или настроить уже существующую.